# Rails image asset not updating in pipeline

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, asset-pipeline

I made a minor change to a `.gif` file we have under our rails `/app/assets` directory.

After running a `rake assets:clean` and `rake assets:precompile` I suddenly have the old version of the `.gif` being referenced in my `/public/assets` directory.

If I delete it from the public directory and rerun the precompile it generates the old file yet again.

What do I have to do to update an image in the asset pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

Odd. Try deleting `APP_ROOT/tmp/cache/assets`